# SliverList inside SliverList

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, dart-pub, flutter-sliver

I've run into large scrolling lists. Sometimes you need to write multiple recursive SliverLists.
I used one package (https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools) to solve this problem but you can't use MutliSliverList as Builder.
This doesn't work properly if you have 10,000 items (lazy loading, etc.)
Also, you can't add a background color for Sliver Lists, which is a little problematic.
Let's find a new way to implement this or something like that?
(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97107)

Comment: When you say multiple lists do you need them to be indecently scrollable ? like a mix of horizontal and vertical scrolls ? if its just one big list of vertical scroll (like a twitter feed) then can't you just assess the index in the builder method and return needed widgets ?

Comment: what's the result you want to achieve? any UI for reference?

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue you are facing?